# ModernCV referencing problem

Tags: cross-referencing, moderncv

I am using moderncv the \cref{} command is not working and if I put the package it, it gives me an error. I tried with \ref it gave me no error but also it never produced any reference just "??" in the place. I want to correct this. Also, I want the label to have a distinct color different from the text. I could not do it in modernCv package. 
Any help appreciated

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{cleveref}

%\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

%\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{section} 
\setcounter{section}{1} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{ Research Experience}
My research experience etc.........
begin{align} 
\label{eq:partitionfunction}
Z(\mathbf{p}; \mathbf{q}; \h) &= \sum_{\lambda \in {\mathcal P}} s_\lambda(p_1, p_2, \ldots) \, s_\lambda(\tfrac{q_1}{\h}, \tfrac{q_2}{\h}, \ldots) \, \prod_{\Box \in \lambda} G(c(\Box) \h) \notag \\
\end{align}

In the above equation \ref{eq:partitionfunction}
```