# Math research statement moderncv

Tags: cross-referencing, moderncv

I am really struggling with writing a Research statement in mathematics using `moderncv`. My problem is that the \ref is not working and when I include the bibtex file produce reference without number. If there is sample math research statement that has theorem, lemma etc and `\ref` `\cite` used. It would be really helpful. 
The latex code I am using is as follows.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{cleveref}

%\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

%\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{section} 
\setcounter{section}{1} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{ Research Experience}
My research experience etc.........
begin{align} 
\label{eq:partitionfunction}
Z(\mathbf{p}; \mathbf{q}; \h) &= \sum_{\lambda \in {\mathcal P}} s_\lambda(p_1, p_2, \ldots) \, s_\lambda(\tfrac{q_1}{\h}, \tfrac{q_2}{\h}, \ldots) \, \prod_{\Box \in \lambda} G(c(\Box) \h) \notag \\
\end{align}

In the above equation \ref{eq:partitionfunction}
```

Comment: There is no mention of `\cite` or even `biblatex` in your document, so I have removed the tag for now. If you also have issues with `biblatex`, please ask a separate question with a suitable example document.

Comment: There are some issues with the code you posted, but those issues may or may not be present in your actual document: (1) The `begin{align}` should be `\begin{align}`. (2) There is no `\end{document}`. (3) The command `\h` is not defined in the example. (4) The document is missing a `\name{<given name>}{<family name>}`. If I change all of these things the `\ref` works after two LaTeX runs. ... That all said, I'm not sure if it is a good idea to work with lemmas, `align`, `\ref` in a `moderncv` document - maybe a more classic document class like `article` would be more appropriate.

Comment: In general, I would not use **moderncv** for anything else than a CV. You don't know, what limitations or surprises this document class has. Just take article for example.

Comment: Please do not ask questions twice (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526122/16550)! If there is no answer in the first question, think about rephrasing it or add more relevant informations to make it clearer ...